# How do I go about displaying a colored house using java with BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class CircleComponent extends JComponent {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
    //Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(50,100,100,100);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fillRect(50,100,100,100);
    g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g2.fillRect(50,80,100,30);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fillRect(100,150,30,50);
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillOval(120, 180, 7, 7);
    //Point2D.Double p = Tester.p;
    g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g2.fillRect(120, 31, 30, 50);
}
}
```

Whenever I do this I get prompted with BlueJ with this (picture is shown):
[Prompting for printing to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtpC.png)

Can somebody please help?

Comment: When you googled the error message and read the posts what did you find about this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't have much of a clue what BlueJ is and not trying to be sarcastic but typically you need a main method to have the class run by itself....

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.*;


public class CircleComponent extends JPanel  {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(50,100,100,100);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fillRect(50,100,100,100);
    g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g2.fillRect(50,80,100,30);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fillRect(100,150,30,50);
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillOval(120,180,7,7);
    //Point2D.Double p = Tester.p;
    g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g2.fillRect(120,31,30,50);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jframe");
    CircleComponent a = new CircleComponent();
    frame.add(a);
    frame.setSize(250,250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.black);

}


}
```